# Is there a spiritual significance to the fact one of the most heavily Jewish neighborhoods in NYC is "Crown" Heights?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, messiah, geography, malchut-royalty, symbols-symbology

This may seem like a strange question but I was curious if there was any religious significance to this. Possibly, Jews following the opinion of a Rabbi who saw the name as signifying a place of belonging or a place related to Jewish symbolism. Thus, Jews started showing up in Brooklyn partly because they associated it with the Jewish faith.

- The "Crown" or the Keter is typically spoken in relation to Kabbalah and the Sefirot. The Keter happens to be the top most point of the tree of life.
- The "Crown" relates to the idea of the Mashiach and how they will eventually come and reestablish the Davidic royal line.
- The "Crown" relates to Hashem and how we identify him as one would identify a king. We are not only taught to give Hashem the respect we would as one does a King, we refer to him as "King" of the universe.

It just seems to me that it makes sense from a religious standpoint that the Jewish people would gather in a place that can symbolically reflect different Jewish themes. That seems like more than just a coincidence to me.

**I was curious if this is a verified idea or not.**

Comment: Borough Park is also heavily Jewish and religious, Brownsville once was as well. What significance would you attach to Monsey, or Lakewood?

Comment: Or New Square/Skver....

Comment: There are some that believe personal given names hold some mystical meaning. I’m not sure it extends to place names, but there may be something to that idea. However, Crown Heights was a heavily Jewish neighborhood well before the Lubavitcher rebbe emigrated to USA. That began to change in the 1950s and 1960s. Despite the hype, the neighborhood’s white (probably Jewish) population is less than 20% today.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crown_Heights,_Brooklyn

Comment: There is spiritual significance to every Jewish neighborhood

Comment: @dude. Even secular?

Comment: There is no spiritual significance. It's simply that Crown Heights is the neighborhood in which the last Lubavitcher Rebbe, R' Yosef Yitzchak Schneerson, decided to live.

Comment: @JJLL Rabbi Kook was of the opinion that even secular Jews were connected to the destiny of the Jewish people even if they weren't spiritually aware of it. Kook actively tried to promote a connection to secular Zionist communities coming to Israel. His mindset was that even if they didn't realize their importance in the bigger picture, they were still involved in a divine plan. It was a controversial position but it made sense considering the 180 Israel took since its rebirth.

Comment: I have to research this. But, I'm fairly confident that the choice of Lubavitch with Crown Heights has about as much "destiny" as the Bostoner Rebbe has to Boston. In short the name Crown Heights was most likely in existence far long before Lubavitch appeared there.

Comment: Gee, I hope this doesn't make all of us whose families live/lived in the Lower East Side or Hell's Kitchen or DUMBO feel bad.

Comment: It gets better actually... Crown Heights has Eastern Parkway (face East when we Daven toward Jerusalem) Union Street (achdus - joining all Jews) President St. (the Nassi or leader of the generation lives there, where the Rebbe's house is located) Crown St. (ditto) Montgomery St. (Mont = "hill" Gomery = powerful-man (old German)) and of course Empire Blvd. Chabad is sort of a world empire at this point... :) Don't forget King-ston Ave. So there is some more fuel for the hashgacha pratis mystics.

Comment: you mean Crow Hill? https://wp.nyu.edu/crownheights/history-and-geography/crow-hill-to-crown-heights/

Comment: There isn't such thing as secular Jew. Every Jew has a holy soul which is connected to Hashem. The spiritual significance of seeing Jews struggling with their observance is they we should help them. This is just like when the mishnah in bava metzia talks about seeing someone's donkey struggling with a load we should help them. It's the jib of every Jew seeing another struggling under the burden of the influences from the physicaity/unholiness if the world to help them lighten their burden

Comment: What about kings county? Or queens? Or dyker heights? Sheesh.

Comment: Only people with large yellow signs with crowns on them think that the name would be significant.

Comment: @DanF Per Wikipedia: Originally, the area was known as Crow Hill. It was a succession of hills running east and west from Utica Avenue to Washington Avenue, and south to Empire Boulevard and East New York Avenue.[2] The name was changed when Crown Street was cut through in 1916.[3] Also per Wikipedia, the 6th Lubavitcher Rebbe moved to America in 1940, so you're right that the name was around for a couple decades prior to Lubavitch's arrival.

Comment: @Salmononius2 Very few towns or villages are named after Jewish rabbis or their ideas / philosophies. The only U.S. village / community that I know of that was formed as well as named after a rebbe is Kiryas Yoel in Orange County, NY.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the Lubavitcher Rebbe made reference to this in his later years. In addition to the address of the center of operations for Chabad Chassidim (770), the Rebbe would often show the spiritual significance of various such details (often including the date at which he spoke), playing on the idea that Hashgacha Pratit holds it that nothing is by chance, and we can learn a lot from seeing that which surrounds us.

Comment: This answer would be a great deal more valuable if you'd [edit] in examples of the Rebbe referring to the significance of the name "Crown Heights" in particular.

Answer (score 0):

the significance of the name crown heights is explained in the second sichah of שבת פרשת בשלח י׳ שבט תשמ״ד

Comment: Please add the summary in English of the write up.